# run_query using dbt and jinja

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I need to create a macro on dbt.

I have systematically 2 distinct values (in date format) in the **date_export** column, the date of the old export and the date of the new export, I have to compare the number of rows in the two **date_export** and **take only the one with several rows**, if the number of rows are **equal** I take the data with **date_export = Min(date_export)**

Here is my code, but I have an error "**'nb_rows_previous' is undefined**" when I try to run the model, anyone have an idea where I screwed up with my code?

```
{% set nb_rows_previous_data_query %}
    select COUNT(*) from {{source(s, table)}}
    WHERE date_export = (SELECT MIN(date_export)) FROM {{source(s, table)}} )
{% endset %}

{% set nb_rows_new_data_query %}
    select COUNT(*) from {{source(s, table)}}
    WHERE date_export = (SELECT MAX(date_export) FROM {{source(s, table)}} )
{% endset %}

{% set results_previous_data = run_query(nb_rows_previous_data_query) %}

{% set results_new_data = run_query(nb_rows_new_data_query) %}

{% if execute %}
    {% set nb_rows_previous = results_previous_data.columns[0][0] %}
    {% set nb_rows_new = results_new_data.columns[0][0] %} 
{% endif %}

{% if nb_rows_previous >= nb_rows_new %}

    SELECT
        {{schema}}
    FROM {{source(s, table)}}
    WHERE date_export = (SELECT MIN(date_export) FROM {{source(s, table)}} )

{% else %}

    SELECT
        {{schema}}
    FROM {{source(s, table)}}
    WHERE date_export = (SELECT MAX(date_export) FROM {{source(s, table)}} )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to persist the value in both `nb_rows_previous` and `nb_rows_new`, you will need to wrap the whole last part of the macro with the `{% if execute %}`, so that it looks like this:

```sql
(...)

{% if execute %}

  {% set nb_rows_previous = run_query(nb_rows_previous_data_query).columns[0][0] %}
  {% set nb_rows_new = run_query(nb_rows_previous_data_query).columns[0][0] %} 

  {% if nb_rows_previous >= nb_rows_new %}

    SELECT
      {{schema}}
    FROM {{source(s, table)}}
    WHERE date_export = (SELECT MIN(date_export) FROM {{source(s, table)}} )

  {% else %}

    SELECT
      {{schema}}
    FROM {{source(s, table)}}
    WHERE date_export = (SELECT MAX(date_export) FROM {{source(s, table)}} )

  {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

By the way, I also changed the code a little bit by doing the run_query command and the value selection in the same line of code